# I want to use a mouseclicked event to an image but it doesn't work

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to use an image as a kind of button, but the only way I could think of is adding a mouse click event to it. this doesn't work yet any ideas? here is my code:

```
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.* ;
import java.io.* ;
import javax.imageio.* ;
import javax.swing.* ;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        new test();
    }

    public test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException |
                    UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Pane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

    }

    public class Pane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;
        private BufferedImage Levels;
        private BufferedImage Exit;
        private BufferedImage PietKiezen;
        private BufferedImage ZwartePiet;
        private BufferedImage Sinterklaas;

        public Pane() {
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new
                        File("C:/Users/H/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Spel/src/Spel/Dak.gif"));
                Levels = ImageIO.read(new
                        File("C:/Users/H/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Spel/src/Spel/Levelsk.gif"));
                Exit = ImageIO.read(new
                        File("C:/Users/H/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Spel/src/Spel/Exitk.gif"));
                PietKiezen = ImageIO.read(new
                        File("C:/Users/H/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Spel/src/Spel/PietKiezen.gif"));
                ZwartePiet = ImageIO.read(new
                        File("C:/Users/H/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Spel/src/Spel/ZwartePiet.gif"));
                Sinterklaas = ImageIO.read(new
                        File("C:/Users/H/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Spel/src/Spel/Sinterklaas.gif"));

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new
            Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
            if (background != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);

            }
            if (PietKiezen != null) {
                int x = 970;
                int y = 130;
                g2d.drawImage(PietKiezen, x, y, this);
            }
            if (Levels != null) {
                int x = 970;
                int y = 260;
                g2d.drawImage(Levels, x, y, this);
            }
            if (Exit != null) {
                int x = 970;
                int y = 390;
                g2d.drawImage(Exit, x, y, this);
            }
            if (ZwartePiet != null) {
                int x = 600;
                int y = 256;
                g2d.drawImage(ZwartePiet, x, y, this);
            }
            if (Sinterklaas != null) {
                int x = 800;
                int y = 256;
                g2d.drawImage(Sinterklaas, x, y, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();

        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            Point clicked = me.getPoint();
            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(172, 62, Exit.getWidth(), Exit.getHeight());
            if (bounds.contains(clicked)) {

                JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(
                        "The only way to close is\n"
                         + "by pressing one of the following buttons.",
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

What I tried to do now is that when the exit image is clicked, there is a pop up screen. why dodn't I get that pop up screen? and is there another way to turn an image into a button without seeing the button it self?

Comment: Draw a rectangle in you paint method, where you "think" the use should click to double check your logic is correct

Comment: *"I am trying to use an image as a kind of button,.."*  Instead use an `Image` as the `ImageIcon` of a `JButton` (undecorated, and possibly with no border) and I'll bet it will work for both mouse and keyboard.

Comment: A `Button` with image will also work good over here. And if don't want the border of button you remove it by using `empty border` that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you need to add a listener to the panel, not create a method (which nobody calls).
Move your method into an anonymous class implementation of a listener in the constructor like so (untested code, use cautiously):

```
public Pane() {
    ...
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            Point clicked = me.getPoint();
            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(172, 62, Exit.getWidth(), Exit.getHeight());
            if (bounds.contains(clicked)) {

                JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(
                        "The only way to close is\n"
                         + "by pressing one of the following buttons.",
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            }
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: you should check your boundaries, that's probably were the problem lies, since you have that `if (bounds.contains(...` line in there. Do a simple test of adding some print out or dialog popup at the beginning of the `mouseClicked` method, and you should see that now you're reacting to mouse click events.

Comment: I still didn't get the pop up screen

Comment: Your code doesn't work since it has A LOT of problems, some of them even prevent it from being compiled. Debug you code first, then you'll see that it works (at least give it a try).

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a MouseListener with your class and you have to register your image icons with MouseListener.

check the sample code below:

```
JPanel signUpPanel = new JPanel();
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, signUpPanel, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, signUpPanel, 100, SpringLayout.EAST, this);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, signUpPanel, 100, SpringLayout.SOUTH, this);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, signUpPanel, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, this);
        signUpPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4, 3, 3));

        facebookIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "facebook.png"));
        facebookIcon.setToolTipText("Facebook SignUp - Automated process");
        facebookIcon.addMouseListener(this);
        signUpPanel.add(facebookIcon); 
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "betvibes.png")));
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "blogger.png")));
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "flickr.png")));
        gmailIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "google.png"));
        gmailIcon.setToolTipText("Gmail SignUp - Automated process");
        gmailIcon.addMouseListener(this);
        signUpPanel.add(gmailIcon);
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "lastfm.png")));
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "linkedin.png")));
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "technorati.png")));
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "twitter.png")));
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "delicious.png")));
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "myspace.png")));
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "reddit.png")));
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "yahoo.png")));
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "vimeo.png")));
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "tumblr.png")));
        signUpPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img" + File.separator + "rss.png")));

        add(signUpPanel);
```